# Python: Conditional probabilities of winning a tiebreaker game

Tags: recursion, python-3.6, probability

This question was asked again ([Excel: Conditional probabilities of winning a tiebreaker game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698815/excel-conditional-probabilities-of-winning-a-tiebreaker-game)), but the OP wanted an Excel-based answer and the one s/he got was not really accurate.

I am trying to calculate the conditional probability of winning a tiebreaker match as described in http://strategicgames.com.au/PhD.pdf,  page 21-22.

It requires coding two recursive formulas:
[Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT5kI.png)
(I cannot attach picture due to low rep)

This is what i've done so far:

```
def prob_tiebraker_game_A(Pa, Pb, a, b):
    if a == 7 and b >= 0 and b <=5:
        return 1
    elif b == 7 and a >= 0 and a <=5:
        return 0
    elif a == 6 and b == 6:
        return (Pa*(1-Pb))/(Pa*(1-Pb) + (1-Pa)*Pb)
    elif (a+b) % 2 ==0:
        return Pa*prob_tiebraker_game_B(Pa, Pb, a+1, b) + (1-Pa)*prob_tiebraker_game_B(Pa, Pb, a,b+1)
    elif (a+b) % 2 !=0:
        return Pa*prob_tiebraker_game_A(Pa, Pb, a+1, b) + (1-Pa)*prob_tiebraker_game_A(Pa, Pb, a,b+1)



 def prob_tiebraker_game_B(Pa, Pb, a, b):
    if b == 7 and a >= 0 and a <=5:
        return 1
    elif a == 7 and b >= 0 and b <=5:
        return 0
    elif a == 6 and b == 6:
        return (Pb*(1-Pa))/(Pb*(1-Pa) + (1-Pb)*Pa)
    elif (a+b) % 2 ==0:
        return Pb*prob_tiebraker_game_A(Pa, Pb, a+1, b) + (1-Pb) * prob_tiebraker_game_A(Pa, Pb, a,b+1)
    elif (a+b) % 2 !=0:
        return Pb*prob_tiebraker_game_B(Pa, Pb, a+1, b) + (1-Pb) *  prob_tiebraker_game_B(Pa, Pb, a,b+1)
```

For values of Pa = 0.62, Pb = 0.6, i should be getting these results:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1gz2.png)

But i am getting the wrong numbers for any values of (a,b) except (0,0) and (6,6), (7,.) and (.,7) since these scores depend on the first 3 conditions in the functions which are trivial to evaluate.

I tried modifying the other conditions but with no success. Any help appreciated would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one recursion. Note `(a+b) mod 2` identifies which player is serving right now. So probability of that player winning/not winning should be used accordingly.Here's the solution when player A is serving.

```
def prob_tiebraker_game(Pa, Pb, a, b):
    if a == 7 and b >= 0 and b <=5:
        return 1
    elif b == 7 and a >= 0 and a <=5:
        return 0
    elif a == 6 and b == 6:
        return (Pa*(1-Pb))/(Pa*(1-Pb) + (1-Pa)*Pb)
    elif (a+b) % 2 != 0:
        # if player A wins (probability Pa) a increases by 1, b remains same
        # if player A doesn't win (probability 1-Pa) b increases by 1, a remains same
        return Pa*prob_tiebraker_game(Pa, Pb, a+1, b) + (1-Pa)*prob_tiebraker_game(Pa, Pb, a, b+1)
    elif (a+b) % 2 == 0:
        # if player B wins (probability Pb) b increases by 1, a remains same
        # if player B doesn't win (probability 1-Pb) a increases by 1, b remains same
        return Pb*prob_tiebraker_game(Pa, Pb, a, b+1) + (1-Pb)*prob_tiebraker_game(Pa, Pb, a+1, b)
```

When player B is serving last two conditions will be swapped. You can write another function for that or combine both into one by adding an additional argument to function that indiciates whether player A served first or not.

Comment: Thanks xashru for such a fast reply! This reproduces the tables perfectly !